# H2DB console application never stops

Tags: java, console-application, h2db

I use hibernate + H2DB:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:./datafile</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
```

but when I do session.close(), it finishes, but my console application never terminates. How can I fix it?

Comment: try adding `System.exit(0);` after `session.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably solution is to close connection factory before exit.